# How do I pass a pointer to a class object between threads and have it persist after the main thread finishes executing?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, pointers, object

Here's the problem that I'm having:

The main thread creates class objects (mybaseclass* local = new childclass;) which are essentially commands that know what they are suppose to do.  It then passes a pointer to the class object to a forked thread over a socket and then the main thread is done with the object and returns waiting for some other input.  The forked thread then reads the pointer from the queue, but the class object that the pointer was pointing to has already been automatically deleted when the main thread completed.  How do I get the class object to persist once the main thread is done executing?

Thanks!
Jeff

Comment: Objects that have been been manually allocated on the heap (i.e. with `new`) are *not* automatically deleted...

Comment: What happens after the main thread ends is not defined (as C++ does not have threads). BUT in most system once the main thread exits all the other threads are killed with extreme prejudice (they do not keep running). Thus  your main thread should wait for all other threads to finish before leaving main().

Comment: Re-Reading you r explanation it is not clear if you are actually using threads. From the words you use `forked`, `spawned` and the fact you are passing objects across a socket. It indicates you are using multiple processes. Processes do not share memory and thus passing pointers is futile.

Comment: As usual this would have been easier to solve if you had posted code rather than an English description.

Answer (score 2):

Objects allocated on the heap with the *new* keyword aren't automatically deleted when a thread completes. If you're positive that it's being automatically deleted, you may have a bug elsewhere. Otherwise, the pointer should still point to a valid object.

Answer (score 2):

In your main thread, create your object on the free store, using `new`:

`mybaseclass* local = new childclass;`

...being sure not to use a smart pointer, as the smart pointer will destroy the object when it falls out of scope.  Pass the pointer to your worker thread via whatever means you are using, then when your worker thread is done with it, delete it:

```
mybaseclass* thread_local = SomehowGetTheObject();
// MAGIC HAPPENS...
delete thread_local;
```

Also, if you are passing around base pointers to derived classes, be sure your base class has a `virtual` destructor.